Security security config in SpringBoot 3
I'm migrating from SpringBoot 2 to SpringBoot3. I'm going to implement authentication based on random generated tokens. Endopoints for login and registration I have done.
I have list of public urls (like /login, /register etc.) and I have filter for authentication. My problem is that when I invoke one of this public urls request is also filtrating (but should not be) and I get 401 status. For rest of endpoints it works fine.
My SecurityConfis.class:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationFilter customAuthenticationFilter;


    /**
     * No authentication endpoints
     */
    public static final RequestMatcher PUBLIC_URLS = new OrRequestMatcher(
            new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/auth/login"),
            new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/auth/register")
    );

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        var protectedUrls = new NegatedRequestMatcher(PUBLIC_URLS);

        http
                .securityMatcher(protectedUrls)
                .cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()))
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .sessionManagement(sessionManagement ->
                        sessionManagement.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .exceptionHandling(exceptionHandling ->
                        exceptionHandling.authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/api/data-transfer/**").hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN")
                        .requestMatchers("/api/discount-code/**").hasAnyAuthority("USER")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .addFilterAfter(customAuthenticationFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {       
    [...]
    }
}

CustomAuthenticationFilter.class
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private static final String BEARER_PREFIX = "Bearer ";

    @Autowired
    private UserCrudService userCrudService;


    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    [...]
    }
}

How to make to not invoke CustomAuthenticationFilter when accessing /api/auth/login or /api/auth/register??

why do you need a custom filter? Why cant you use the built in JWT support in spring security

@Toerktumlare I want to have possibility to customize authentication therefore I need my own filter.

What kind of customization, why cant you customize the built in jwt support?

Try adding .requestMatchers("/api/auth/login", ("/api/auth/register").permitAll() to SecurityFilterChain.

I've found the solution. The problem was silly, because while accessing /api/auth/login I was adding "Authentication" header.
Because there was incorrect authentication data, CustomAuthenticationFilter was throwing exception and I got unauthorized.
Sending request without "Authorization" header fixed problem. Of course for secured endpoints this header is required.
